# D3.JS Area Chart Incorrect Orientation Fill "How does the number of Deaths in New York City change by year."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a simple time series area chart. I am trying to visualize how the number of Deaths in New York City change by year. The following code produces an area chart; however, the line of the graph and the fill are moving downward across the Y-Axis (Please see image below). I would like the line and area to go horizontally across the X-axis instead. I've looked over my code multiple times and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated!?

Dataset:https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/New-York-City-Leading-Causes-of-Death/jb7j-dtam/data

```
/* CONSTANTS AND GLOBALS */
const width = window.innerWidth * 0.7,
height = window.innerHeight * 0.7,
margin = { top: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100, right: 60 };

/* LOAD DATA */
d3.csv('../data/New_York_City_Leading_Causes_of_Death.csv', d => {
return {
  Year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // Remove commas from Year,
  //Year: +d.Year, 
  Deaths: +d.Deaths
}
}).then(data => {
console.log('data :>> ', data);

// SCALES
const xScale = d3.scaleTime() 
 .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.Year))
 .range([margin.left, width-margin.right])
 
 

const yScale =  d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.Deaths))
 .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

// CREATE SVG ELEMENT
const svg =d3.select("#container")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .style("background-color", "aliceblue")

// BUILD AND CALL AXES
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.format("d"))

const xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "xAxis")
.attr("transform", `translate(${0},${height - margin.bottom})`)
.call(xAxis)

xAxisGroup.append("text")
.attr("class", 'xLabel')
.attr("transform", `translate(${width}, ${35})`)
.text("Year") 

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
// .tickFormat(formatBillions)

const yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "yAxis")
.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${0})`)
.call(yAxis)


// AREA GENERATOR FUNCTION
const areaGen = d3.area()
  .x(d => xScale(d.Year))
  .y0(height - margin.bottom) // Set the bottom of the area to the bottom of the chart
  .y1(d => yScale(d.Deaths));


svg.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("fill", "#7FFFD4")
.attr("stroke", "#B22222")
.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
.attr("d", areaGen(data));

});
```

[image: Area Chart]

The following code produces an area chart; however, the line of the graph and the fill are moving downward across the Y-Axis (Please see image below). I would like the line and area to go horizontally across the X-axis instead

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your data is not properly sorted by year.

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.Year < b.Year ? -1 : 1);
```

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      /* CONSTANTS AND GLOBALS */
      const width = window.innerWidth * 0.7,
        height = window.innerHeight * 0.7,
        margin = { top: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100, right: 60 };

      /* LOAD DATA */
      const raw = [
        {
          item: '2019',
          count: '150',
        },
        {
          item: '2016',
          count: '145',
        },
        {
          item: '2007',
          count: '141',
        },
        {
          item: '2011',
          count: '141',
        },
        {
          item: '2015',
          count: '141',
        },
        {
          item: '2010',
          count: '138',
        },
        {
          item: '2018',
          count: '137',
        },
        {
          item: '2017',
          count: '136',
        },
        {
          item: '2014',
          count: '136',
        },
        {
          item: '2008',
          count: '136',
        },
        {
          item: '2009',
          count: '135',
        },
        {
          item: '2012',
          count: '134',
        },
        {
          item: '2013',
          count: '133',
        },
      ];

      const data = raw.map((d) => ({ Year: +d.item, Deaths: +d.count }));
      data.sort((a, b) => a.Year < b.Year ? -1 : 1);

      // SCALES
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Year))
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

      const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Deaths))
        .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

      // CREATE SVG ELEMENT
      const svg = d3
        .select('#container')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .style('background-color', 'aliceblue');

      // BUILD AND CALL AXES
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

      const xAxisGroup = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'xAxis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${0},${height - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      xAxisGroup
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'xLabel')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${width}, ${35})`)
        .text('Year');

      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
      // .tickFormat(formatBillions)

      const yAxisGroup = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'yAxis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${0})`)
        .call(yAxis);

      // AREA GENERATOR FUNCTION
      const areaGen = d3
        .area()
        .x((d) => xScale(d.Year))
        .y0(height - margin.bottom) // Set the bottom of the area to the bottom of the chart
        .y1((d) => yScale(d.Deaths));

      svg
        .append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('fill', '#7FFFD4')
        .attr('stroke', '#B22222')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .attr('d', areaGen(data));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```